# jQuery custom selecting method works on first element of collection only

Tags: javascript, jquery

At some point I decided I need a handy jQuery selector to select `td:nth-child` of rows from x to y. Rather than writing a `[:]` expression selector, I went for a plugin method - assuming that it should work just as fine as `.find()` or `.prevAll()` does.

```
$.fn.nthTdInRows = function (n, sRow, eRow) {
  return this
    .filter(function (index, el) {
      return el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'table';
     })
    .find('tr')
    .filter(function (index) {
      return index + 1 >= sRow && index + 1 <= eRow;
    })
    .find('td:nth-child(' + n + ')');
}
```

Although this code work, it works only for the first table in collection. That's most probably due to lack of `.each()` within the plugin, but I somehow couldn't wrap my mind around how to use it when a return value is desired. Can this be done along the path I have chosen?

Comment: So are you wanting to say `$(collectionOfTables).nthTdInRows(n, sRow, eRow)` and have it return an array of jQuery collections with each element in the array representing the results of your function for each table in the `collectionOfTables`?

Comment: Yes, correct. I basically need to operate on a single table, but I would sleep well if I ended up with a lame plugin.

Comment: Okay, check my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so here is how you can get it to give you an array of jQuery collections back for each table. Let me know if this is what you were looking for:

#### Update -- returned a single jQuery collection of DOM elements, rather than a collection of collections so that you can chain jQuery functions off of the `.nthTdInRows()` call.

```js
$.fn.nthTdInRows = function(n, sRow, eRow) {
  var arr = this.map(function() { // <-- this calls the following code for each table 
    // passed in, and maps each return value into an array element

    var tables = $(this).filter(function(index, el) {
      return $(this).is("table");
    });
    var tableRows = tables.find("tr");
    var indexedRows = tableRows.filter(function(index) {
      return index + 1 >= sRow && index + 1 <= eRow;
    });
    var tds = indexedRows.find('td:nth-child(' + n + ')');
    return tds;
  });
  //debugger;
  var collection = [];
  arr.each(function() {
    // flatten arr into simple array of DOM elements, rather than nested jQuery collections
    collection = collection.concat($.map(this, function(elem, index) {
      return elem;
    }));
  });
  // wrap array of DOM elements with jQuery object so we can chain off of nthTdInRows()
  return $(collection);
}

$(function() {
  var tables = $("#table1, #table2, #table3");
  tables.nthTdInRows(2, 1, 4).addClass("highlight");
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="table1">
    <tr>
      <th>header1</th>
      <th>header2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data1-1</td>
      <td>data2-1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data1-2</td>
      <td>data2-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data1-3</td>
      <td>data2-3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data1-4</td>
      <td>data2-4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="table2">
    <tr>
      <th>header3</th>
      <th>header4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data3-1</td>
      <td>data4-1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data3-2</td>
      <td>data4-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data3-3</td>
      <td>data4-3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data3-4</td>
      <td>data4-4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="table3">
    <tr>
      <th>header5</th>
      <th>header6</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data5-1</td>
      <td>data6-1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data5-2</td>
      <td>data6-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data5-3</td>
      <td>data6-3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data5-4</td>
      <td>data6-4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: purrfect - I forgot completely about `.map()` in jQuery, although I am using it daily in ES6! Will adjust the code to focus on `tbody`. Thanks!

Comment: @nuton Also, keep in mind that you can use jQuery inside your plugins for selectors and such. Your `el.tagName()...` can be simplified to `$(this).is("table")`

Comment: Sure thing, good point - I mixed techniques here. Is there a way to simplify the usage by not having to call `each`? Meaning: instead of `var matchingTDs = tables.nthTdInRows(2, 1, 4); matchingTDs.each(function() { $(this).addClass("highlight") });` rather say: `tables.nthTdInRows(2, 1, 4).addClass("highlight");` ? Just like with built-in jQuery selectors.

Comment: Well, not all built-in jQuery functions return a collection that you can call a method that will apply to all on. For example `$("#table1, #table2, #table3").attr("id")` will only give you the ID of the first table in the collection - it does not give you an array of IDs. Arguably it probably *could*, but it's not implemented that way. What you could do is flatten the array after the `.map()` call with a `.reduce()`. I will update my solution

Comment: @nuton Okay try it now

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your time and commitment! A good lesson learned.

Comment: @nuton You're welcome =) Upvotes are always appreciated! Side note -- I mentioned using `.reduce()` in a previous comment, but I misspoke. I forgot that reduce is not a method on a jQuery collection, which is why I had to use `$.map` and `.each` instead.